# Using subprocess to start multiple programs

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to use a Python script to start multiple programs.  The issue that I'm facing is that while the first of those programs executes as expected in a shell, the second program never does.  Is there a way to start the first program and *not* have subprocess wait to start the second?

I've tried using the `call` function from the `subprocess` module, having the main program wait 5 seconds and then start the second.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['xxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'shell=True'])
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.call(['xxx', '-x', 'xxxxxx'])
```

I want the program to start each of these programs in a shell, but only the first program ever starts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Popen` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) from the `subprocess` module directly in order to start processes in the background.

As it effectively *starts* a process, but doesn't wait for it to finish, I like to rename it to `start` in code. Like so:

```
from subprocess import Popen as start
process = start('python process.py')
```

As in your example, you may just give the process, or each of the processes, enough time to finish. However, it may be advisable to wait for them to finish individually before you exit the calling script:

```
from subprocess import Popen as start

processes = []

for i in range(3):
    process = start(f'python process{i}.py')
    processes.append(process)

for process in processes:
    process.wait()
```

Refer to the [documentation of the `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) module in order to decide if adding the option `shell=True` is actually needed for the purpose of running your external process.

Comment: I tried your first solution and it worked, to a point.  The code did start both programs, however, it tried to open the second program in the same term window as the first.  When this happened, the second program errored, but the first continued.  Is there a way to launch 3 separate shells?

Comment: Ok.  Perhaps I should have stated that this was on a Linux system.  Also, I am trying to get each to execute in separate window.  These are long running programs and they should run until explicitly stopped.  Thanks for your input!!  At least now I'm a step further than I was!